# BroadcastReceiver for incoming calls

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

In my application I want to get notified when a call comes in. For this I created a BroadcastReceiver which looks like this:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    MyPhoneStateListener phoneListener = new MyPhoneStateListener();

    TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telephony.listen(phoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
}

private class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener
{
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber)
    {
        if(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) incommingCall(incomingNumber);
        else if(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) endingCall(incomingNumber);
    }

    //...
}
```

My problem now is that this Receiver is never called. I have registered it in the Manifest like this:

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.cilenco.interrupts.ContactControl"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
    </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

Is something wrong with this? Or is this a Receiver I can not register from the Manifest? If so do you have other ideas how to implement this without the user has to start my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make you `android:exported="false"` attribute to true

```
android:exported="true"
```

so that android OS can send the broadcasts to your application , if you specify exported to false android OS will ignore yours application.

Answer (score -1):

```
    Try this one:



     public class Incomingcallreceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      Do your stuff


        }

        }
```

Add this in the manifset to register the receiver for the call

```
     <receiver
            android:name="com.example.enwaye_connect.Incomingcallreceiver"
            android:label="Incomingcallreceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Add permission also

```
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
```

Comment: Why u minus that answer